# Message and groups are not on sync : Skype 4.3.2 Ubuntu 12.04 and https://web.skype.com

Tags: 12.04, skype, sync

Since few days Skype is not syncing groups and messages on Ubuntu 12.04 sent from https://web.skype.com/en/

I did below things to resolve

1. Removed Skype
2. Download latest http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64
3. $ rm ~/.Skype/* -rf
4. Re install it

But still messages and groups are not sync

[image: Recent Chats on Ubuntu 12.04]
[image: Recent Chats on Web Skype]

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:
https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-4-3-0-37-IM-s-do-not-sync-with-Android-devices-but-Android/td-p/4446446

tldr; version:
open any chat window, type /msnp24 in there and after that "Restart and be a happy MSNP24 user :)" message should appear. Restart and you should be good to go. worked for me at least :)